# Python column entries selection

Tags: python

How can we simply transform the values in column 'colors' into column 'new_colors' in Python as indicated below?

```
    colors        new_colors
0   red          red
1   blue;yellow  blue
2   red;green    red
```

Do we need to apply the split method to 'colors' column or is there a simpler way of approaching this so that 'new_colors' only shows the first color in 'colors'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `str.split`:

```
df['new_colors'] = df['colors'].str.split(';').str[0]
```

Or try:

```
df['new_colors'] = df['colors'].str.replace(';.*', '')
```

Comment: Thanks @U12-Forward, I tried that one before, I am just wondering if there is any other way to approach this.

Comment: @Tristan Added another one

Comment: @Tristan AH! Just got a super better one! Check it out

Comment: Cool @U12-Forward, it returns similar results as the split method. Thanks a lot!